# can not import image from local file with require keywork react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a react native project. I currently have a list I want to render dynamically based on an array of objects that I have. One of the key values in the array is `image:'name.png'`. I am passing in the object in to a flatlist. Each element in the array has a different image file name.

Inside of each element I want to render the image and for the image item, I am try8ing to currently use the `require` key word with a string that will render the images but it is currently not rendering I am not sure why. What should I do.

flatlist:

```
  const homeTypeOptions1 = [
    {
      key: 1,
      value: 'Houses',
      image: 'home.png'
    },
    {
      key: 2,
      value: 'Condos',
      image: 'building.png'
    },
    {
      key: 3,
      value: 'Lot/Land',
      image: 'management.png'
    },
    {
      key: 4,
      value: 'Multi-family',
      image: 'multi-family.png'
    },
    {
      key: 5,
      value: 'Manufactured',
      image: 'tiny-house.png'
    },
    {
      key: 6,
      value: 'Townhomes',
      image: 'townhouse.png'
    }
  ]

  <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
    <FlatList 
      style={styles.homeTypeContainer}
      data={homeTypeOptions1}
      keyExtractor={(item) => {item.key}}
      numColumns={numberOfColumns}
      renderItem={(item) => {return(<GridItemComponent item={item}/>)}}
    />
  </View>
```

itemComponent:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native'

const GridItemComponent = ({item}) => {
  const imageUrl = '../../assets/' + item.item.image

  return (
    <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
      <Image source={require('../../assets/' + item.item.image)}/>
      <Text>{item.item.value}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  itemContainer: {
    width: '33%',
  }
})

export default GridItemComponent
```

Here is the folder structure:

[image: folder structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `item.image` and `item.value`

```jsx
const GridItemComponent = ({item}) => {
  const imageUrl = '../../assets/' + item.image;

  return (
    <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
      <Image source={require(imageUrl)}/>
      <Text>{item.value}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

and the *keyExtractor* should be

```jsx
keyExtractor={(item) => item.key}
```

Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#description